# Declaring associations in DataMapper on ruby?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I need to create a database with following tables: **School**, **Address**, **Years**, **Types** and **Results**.
Each **School** can have only *one* **Address** and *many* **Years**, each **Year** must have *many* **Types**, and each **Type** at *each* **Year** can have only *one* **Results** table.

There is my DataMapper model declining:

```
class School
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String, :length => 225, :required => true
  property :type, String

  has n, :years
  has 1, :address
  has n, :types, :through => :years
  has n, :visits
end

class Year
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :year, Integer

  has n, :types
  has n, :schools

end

class Result
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :subject, String, :length => 225
  property :total, Integer
  property :range_1, Integer
  property :range_2, Integer
  property :range_3, Integer
  property :range_4, Integer
  property :range_5, Integer
  property :range_6, Integer
  property :range_7, Integer
  property :range_8, Integer
  property :range_9, Integer
  property :range_10, Integer

  belongs_to :type
end

class Type
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String, :length => 225, :required => true

  has n, :results
  has n, :years
  has n, :schools, :through => :years
end

class Address
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :Village, String
  property :City, String
  property :District, String
  property :State, String

  belongs_to :school
end
```

I can't find a better way for declaring associations between tables. Maybe you can propose something better?

And also, how can I select the specific results which depends on school and a year?

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? What is it that you want to accomplish that this current implementation is not giving you?